# Field order between Source and Source Qualifier need to be same?

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

This is might be a basic question but just curious to know, My source is a flat file and do we need to maintain same field order between source and source qualifier objects in Informaitca?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No but you need to maintain field order against list of fields returned by the query... especially if you use an sql override

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not.
You even may need to change this order if you are going to Sort data by Source Qualifier. If you set integer value for ‘*Number of Sorted Ports*’ SQ property Informatica Information Service(IS) will look at that number of ports starting at the top. So, you may need to rearrange ports order by moving sorting ports at top.